# How can I "override" [] to accept two arguments in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to create a bit-vector class in C++ to model some hardware.  In most HDLs (hardware description langauges) that I know, specific bits are referenced like this:

```
my_vector[bit_position]
```

and sub-vectors are referenced like this:

```
my_vector[msb:lsb]
```

or

```
my_vector[msb,lsb]
```

I want to be able to do something similar with my bit-vector class.  Is there any way to tell `operator[]` to accept two arguments?

The alternatives I've considered are:

1. using a `range` method:

   `my_vector.range(msb,lsb)`
2. using a string and parsing it:

   `my_vector["msb:lsb"]`

But neither of them is attractive. The first, because it is too different from the way it's modeled in HDL, the second because I don't like dealing with strings when I don't have to, and it seems inelegant.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you feel about the syntax my_vector<1,2> ?

Comment: @Eric: that's fine. how would I go about doing that?  Doesn't that require a template definition?

Comment: -1 for implementing "cool" things. Buy a copy of C++ standard and read it. (e.g. ISO/IEC 14882:2003, ch 13.5.5: operator[] shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter). You will not be able to "simulate" all syntax of VHDL in C++, so why not using methods (I should give you +1 for considering alternative 1 :-) ). Also good readings in this context are: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/unmain.html and http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.14

Comment: @Valentin: that rules out most of Boost. Luckily, these people weren’t so inflexible.

Comment: C++0x allows you to use a string and parse it at compile time. But, that would still be a pain in the butt. I agree that `operator[]` should do this :v( .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The issue:

> Apart from `operator()` all operators have a fixed arity, which effectively precludes any kind of change

You then have several solutions:

- overload `operator()` instead: `vector(msb, lsb)`
- use two successive invocations: `vector[msb][lsb]`
- overload the comma operator: `vector[msb,lsb]`

The last solution matches the syntax you require, but is somewhat subtle:

- you first need either `msb` or `lsb` to be of a custom type (for operators cannot be overloaded on built-ins only)
- you then provide an overload of `operator,` for this type, returning a `Range` object
- you finally provide a custom `operator[](Range)` on your class

The real bummer is the first point: that one of `msb` or `lsb` need be of a custom type. This can be somewhat alleviated using `Boost.StrongTypedef` which creates a custom type that mimicks an existing one.

Comment: Overloading the comma operator... that's extremely unusual, and likely to trip people up.  See also point 20 of http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.9

Comment: @user9876: indeed it is unusual, I mentioned it for completeness though. I would personally use the second solution (successive invocations) since it allows me to "cache" the proxy object in tight loops.

Comment: @user9876:  In this case it's probably less confusing, since it's only used as part of a special usage.  Of course, if somebody uses a comma operator in one of the parts of a `for` statement, it's confusion time.

Comment: If you want to override comma, you could also use `#define _r (range_intro)` with `my_bits[_r 25, 32 ]` or the like. The cast turns the first integer into your custom type, the nomenclature is legal but unlikely to conflict with anything, and it's a hack, but it properly *looks* like a hack, yet unobtrusively.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I am in the habit of using macros with names like `PROJECT_FILE_NAME` to avoid conflict, so I guess the define would not work :) As said, using a custom type (or converting to) would work, however the is always the risk of a user using the comma "normally" and being utterly confused as a result. I think we all agree that both `()` and `[][]` are clearer and should be preferred.

Comment: Yes… it's worth noting, though, that the most common usage of the comma is to separate function arguments, which is exactly what happens when you overload it here. I personally don't like `()` for subscripting, and `[][]` means something else entirely. Consider the interaction with `operator[](int)` used to access single bits.

Comment: Can `operator()` be overloaded to accept any number of arguments?

Comment: @Nathan: yes it can, which is why this is the usual recommendation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I agree, C++ thrive on ambiguities and using the comma for multiple roles: function argument separator, sequence point and possibly operator; is what prevents us from having a non-hacky syntax :/

Answer (score 20):

a simple struct with two members as a parameter to operator[]...

```
struct pos
{
  int lsb;
  int msb;
};

pos foo={1,2};

my_vector[foo];
```

or in the new standard, I believe you can simply do:

```
my_vector[pos{1,2}]
```

Comment: Even with the old standard, you can give `pos` a constructor and write `my_vector[pos(1,2)]`, which isn't too bad. In this case it should be called `range`, not `pos`, since we're extracting a sub-range, not addressing in 2 dimensions.

Comment: This is actually very elegant!

Comment: Yes, similar to what I was going to suggest simply using a std::pair. +1

Comment: @Steve Jessop, I was going to call it foo! :) but range is more appropriate!

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to tell `operator[]` to accept two arguments?

No.

There's two common alternatives. One is to overload `operator()` instead. You then have to invoke it using the `()` syntax.

The other one is to have `operator[]` return a ***proxy object*** for which `operator[]` is overloaded, too. This can be invoked like multi-dimensional arrays in C, with several `[][]` in series.

Comment: I think that the multi-dimensional array syntax is a bit rubbish in this case, where we're actually after a sub-range. `myvector[0][8]` doesn't obviously mean, "the first 8 bits of `myvector`" as the questioner wants, so a function would almost certainly be better.

Comment: @Steve. This is certainly true. (I just answered the question as quoted, and obviously forgot about the context.) That's the reason I up-voted [Nim's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977817/how-can-i-override-to-accept-two-arguments-in-c/3977854#3977854) instead.

Answer (score 4):

The usual solution is to override the () operator.  This lets you do things like my_vector(1, 2).

Work arounds using the [] operator are possible, but as Matthieu M. points out, you need a custom type to be involved.

Comment: Won't work unless "1" is of a type you can add an operator,() to.  Which it isn't.

Comment: I like your second alternative … although I’m not convinced that it works.

Comment: This is always an amusing read about how you can abuse C++ to achieve your own ends: http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/analogliterals.xhtml

Comment: @Eric Towers: I would do it as follows.  In the range class, override the casting operator so that a range can be implicitly created from an integer.  You would need to be able to construct a "partial" range for this (i.e. only one element).  Then override the comma operator to accept (int, range) and return a "completed" partial range.

Comment: @Eric: does that actually work, though? I haven't tried it, but do you get the route with the conversion and the call to the overloaded `operator,`, when `1,2` is already a perfectly good expression?

Comment: @Steve: I'd really like to know about it too, always thought I had to use a "better" type than a built-in. Never really looked into it though, since I am in favor of strong typing and I would typically have a `HigherBit` and `LowerBit` class here, just to make sure I don't mix them up.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: It should.  Matthieu M. has more details in his answer.  The problem with just ``1,2'' is that the comma operator eats the first operand and returns just the second so that without the cast/comma overloads in place [1,2] is equivalent to [2].

Comment: @Eric:  Won't work.  int is an internal type so type inference will stop at int and not attempt to find a user-defined cast that will get the job done.

Comment: @Eric: not if there’s no overload for `operator [](int)`. Then it *must* find a conversion. However, I fear that the sequence point will be evaluated *before* that (this should happen) and only the value of the sequence point (i.e. `2` in the example) will be passed to the `range` class constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Two argument operator[] is not possible in C++.  The names of, precedence of, associativity of, and arity of operators is fixed by the language.[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.7)  Operator() however can take two arguments...

Answer (score -1):

use a language with array slices instead? =P

Comment: that would be an option if the codebase I'm working on weren't in C++

Comment: C++ has array slices as `std::slice`, they just don't work very well :vP