# C++ indexing with an operator overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

In class A, LINE_1 works very well however, in class B, LINE_2 doesn't work. It it possible to make it work LINE_2 using the same concept shown in the LINE_1? Class A and B defined as follows:

```
 class A{
      private:
         vector<int> a;
      public:
         A(){}
         A(int i){
             a.clear();
             a.resize(i,0);
        }
       ~A(){}   

 int & operator[](int i) {return a[i];} //LINE_1 

 //LINE_1 :: index operator: example a[5]=-1; it works
};

 class B{
     private:
         vector<vector<int> > b;
     public:
         B(){}
         B(int i, int j){
          b.clear();
          b.resize(j, vector<int>(i, 0));
         }
       ~B(){}

    int& operator[](int i,int j) {return a[i][j];} //LINE_2

    //LINE_2:: index operator, want to use like b[2][3]=-1; it doesn't work

    int&  operator()(int i, int j) {return a[i][j];} //LINE_3

    //LINE_3:: index operator, b(2,3)=-1; it works 
};
```

example:

```
   int main ()
   {
    A a(10);
    a[0]=-1// it works
    B b(10, 10);
    b[2][3]=-1; //doesn't work
    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: See this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977817/how-can-i-override-to-accept-two-arguments-in-c/3977854#3977854

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate question. Thank you for giving reference. I will delete this question.